# Why is the Ajax call not executing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table where each record can be deleted by the user:

```
<td style='text-align: center;'>
  <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs delete' id=9 data-title='Delete' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete' >
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>
  </button>
</td>
```

The `jQuery` / `AJAX` call is:

```
$('.delete').click(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(id);
  bootbox.confirm("Are you sure? ", function(r) {
    if (r) { // Sent request to delete order with given id
      alert('SENT REQUEST');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'delete.php',
        data: 'id='+id,
        success: function(b) {
          if (b) { // Delete row
            alert('YES');
            // orTable.fnDeleteRow($('tr#' + id)[0]);
           } else { // Failed to delete
             alert('NO');
             noty({
               text: "There is a problem deleting this record, try again",
               layout: "topCenter",
               type: "alert",
               timeout: 3
             });
           }
         }
      });
      document.location.reload();   
    }
  });
});
```

And the delete.php is

```
if($_GET['id']) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];   
   $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM debiteuren WHERE id = " . $id;
   mysqli_query($link,$sql_delete) or die(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Any idea why it isn't working?

I get the alert id and the modal "Are you sure?" and the alert "SEND REQUEST". But after that, the page reload and the record with ID = 9 hasn't been deleted.

Kind regards,,

Arie

Comment: You are not sending anything back from server!

Comment: Try this in your `php` script: `$res=mysqli_query($link,$sql_delete);
if($res)
{
echo array('status'=>true);
}
else
{
echo array('status'=>false);
}` and read `response.status` after _parsing_ the response..

Comment: in query you can use $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM debiteuren WHERE id = $id ";  without concatenate

Comment: why aren't you doing a simple form submit if you are refreshing the page?

Comment: Time to read up on [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax is executes async try to reload the page after the ajax completed:

```
$('.delete').click(function(e) {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(id);
      bootbox.confirm("Are you sure? ", function(r) {
        if (r) { // Sent request to delete order with given id
            alert('SENT REQUEST');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'delete.php',
                data: {id:id},
                success: function(b) {
                    if (b) { // Delete row
                        alert('YES');
                        // orTable.fnDeleteRow($('tr#' + id)[0]);
                    } else { // Failed to delete
                        alert('NO');
                        noty({
                            text: "There is a problem deleting this record, try again",
                            layout: "topCenter",
                            type: "alert",
                            timeout: 3
                        });

                    }
                     document.location.reload(); 
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

and as  Rayon Dabre suggested return something from the php page

Note use `data-id="9"` for valid html

Comment: Indeed, the reload line wasn't on the right place!
But the returning part from  the php I don't understand, I have put 
if($res) { echo array('status'=>true); } else { echo array('status'=>false); }
but what must I do to handle this in the jquery?
It works fine now, so how important is it to handle the response?

Comment: encode it: `echo json_encode(array('status'=>true));`, to get it in the success function of ajax call just type `data.status`

Answer (score 1):

I feel you are `reload()`ing at wrong place, that should be moved inside `success` callback.

```
success: function(b) {
    if (b) { // Delete row
        alert('YES');
        // orTable.fnDeleteRow($('tr#' + id)[0]);
    } else { // Failed to delete
        alert('NO');
        noty({
            text: "There is a problem deleting this record, try again",
            layout: "topCenter",
            type: "alert",
            timeout: 3
        });
    }
    document.location.reload();  //<-----move it here.
}
```

And i guess you will get alert of `NO` everytime because you are not sending the proper response back from the server.